# Problems trying to reload navigation properties

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6.2.0 with MySQL.

I have two relations: *People* and *Biometrics*. When people enroll biometrics with another application, I want to show the changes.

So, I wrote this:

```
  var Context = (MyDbContext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
  Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, People.Biometrics);
```

This works only when people discard the Biometrics. Then a collection that once had data now is correctly empty. However when a collection is already empty, and someone adds biometrics, then the data doesn't get loaded.

So I tried the following code:

```
  MyDbContext.Entry(entity).Collection(c => c.Biometrics).Load();
```

With no success. I also tried this:

```
  MyDbContext.Entry(entity).Reload();
  MyDbContext.Entry(entity).Collection(c => c.Biometrics).Load();
```

Also with no success.

Comment: All those functions work with local data, while you need to fetch data from mysql server. Are there any sql queries being executed by that code?

Comment: I don't know. How can I see? This is how I loaded the data: *MyDbContext.People.Include(e => e.Biometrics).Load();*
and *var ps = MyDbContext.People.Local;* these are code executed before the code I showed in the question. Don't know if it clarifies something.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception there, just use the debug output and check if any queries are being generated by Refresh and Reload.

Comment: The Context.Refresh logs a query only when I discard data in the database. When I insert data it logs nothing. The Collection().Load() method always logs queries. Although the properties are still not updated.